# BigCommerce - Displat product information like name, url, description on home page

Tags: bigcommerce

BigCommerce - Displat product information like name, url, description on home page. I am trying to use "%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%" but this global variable not working in home page. I am new in the bigcommerce. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

BigCommerce's Blueprint template variables are only available in certain scopes.  Many of the product-related variables will only return values when they're used inside the ProductDetails panel, for example.

On the homepage, you can use the HomeFeaturedProducts and HomeNewProducts panels to display product listings.  Variables like %%GLOBAL_ProductName%% are available for these products inside the snippets HomeFeaturedProductsItem and HomeNewProductsItem, respectively.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!!! I know this way but i can't use this way because i need different layout or design of product list for only homepage.

Comment: Understandable, there definitely isn't a lot of flexibility on the homepage regarding products, you're kind of bound by what BigCommerce makes available in the markup.  In the past, I've used the featured products panel and associated snippet to generate custom product layouts on the homepage.  You could fetch the needed product info via AJAX and render it without any layout limitations, but that can be complex & less than desirable for SEO.  I've used SearchSpring and Algolia to do this for a couple more exotic BC implementations in the past, but neither is free, and SEO becomes a challenge.